# JavaScript prototype, how can I assign a variable while chaining?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, prototype

I'm studying react. I have a trouble with using prototype.

I want to assign a variable while chaining. The number of array returned by `slice` function should be assigned on `count` state.

What I want to implement is not to go to the page which is over the count of contents. To implement that, I thought I should assign `count` state when `slice` function is working. How can I assign `count`?

I typed codes in sandbox.
https://codesandbox.io/s/blissful-rosalind-15e7od?file=/src/App.js
Below is the same contents.

```js
import "./styles.css";
import React, { useState } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const rows = [
    { id: 1, name: "a" },
    { id: 2, name: "b" },
    { id: 3, name: "c" },
    { id: 4, name: "d" },
    { id: 5, name: "e" },
    { id: 6, name: "f" },
    { id: 7, name: "g" },
    { id: 8, name: "h" },
    { id: 9, name: "i" },
    { id: 10, name: "j" },
    { id: 11, name: "k" },
    { id: 12, name: "l" }
  ];

  const [count, setCount] = useState(rows.length);
  const [page, setPage] = useState(0);
  const [rowsPerPage, setRowsPerPage] = useState(3);

  const handleLeft = () => {
    page > 1 && setPage(page - 1);
  };

  const handleRight = () => {
    page < Math.ceil(count / rowsPerPage) && setPage(page + 1);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <h3>
        count: {count}, page: {page}, rowsPerPage: {rowsPerPage}
      </h3>
      <button onClick={handleLeft}>left</button>
      <button onClick={handleRight}>right</button>
      {rows
        .filter((item) => item.id > 3)
        .slice(
          ...(rowsPerPage > 0
            ? [page * rowsPerPage, page * rowsPerPage + rowsPerPage]
            : [])
        )
        .map((item) => (
          <div key={item.id}>{item.id}</div>
        ))}
    </>
  );
}
```

Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: why do you need this array count? Assign to a variable while chaining with in return. I'm not sure that is the right way to do it.I can post another way with useMemo if you needed

Comment: I added why I need array count on this post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you try something like [this sandbox link](https://codesandbox.io/s/agitated-ptolemy-nss0ny?file=/src/App.js)

Is there any specific reason as to why you wish to proceed with updating the prototype for your use case?

[UPDATED SANDBOX LINK]

Please find your solution on below link. There's some problem with the pagination logic but I am sure you'll take care of it. Hope the below sandbox link helps

[Link](https://codesandbox.io/s/hardcore-grothendieck-jl3zmx?file=/src/App.js&resolutionWidth=320&resolutionHeight=675)

Comment: I didn't come up with using sandbox. I added it. Thanks for your opinion.

I added contents that I want to do too. Is it possible to assign state not to update prototype? To assign state I thought I should update it.

Comment: @seunghyeon I have updated my answer and attached the working solution for your sandbox link. Look for 'Link'

Comment: @seunghyeon In the solution on page 3,4 where there are no items being displayed the count goes back to 0.Do upvote if this is what you were looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Custom hooks implementation

```
const usePagination = (data = [], rowPerPage = 3) => {
  const [currentpage, setCurrentPage] = useState(0);
  const totalItems = data.length;
  const maxPages = Math.ceil(totalItems / rowPerPage);

  const next = () => {
    setCurrentPage((page) => {
      const _page = page + 1;
      return _page < maxPages ? _page : page;
    });
  };
  const prev = () => {
    setCurrentPage((page) => {
      const _page = page - 1;
      return _page >= 0 ? _page : page;
    });
  };
  const itemsToList = useMemo(() => {
    const start = currentpage * rowPerPage;
    const end = start + rowPerPage;
    return data.slice(start, end);
  }, [rowPerPage, currentpage, data]);

  return {
    prev,
    next,
    itemsToList,
    maxPages,
    totalItems,
    currentpage
  };
};
```

code sandbox [link](https://codesandbox.io/s/angry-morning-wvh6sn?file=/src/App.js)